# Return multiple values from a method

Tags: c#

Hi guys i'm having a problem regarding returning multiple values from a method. I'm using 'out' to return other value from a method, here the snippet:

```
public DataTable ValidateUser(string username, string password, out int result)
{
    try
    {
        //Calls the Data Layer (Base Class)
        if (objDL != null)
        {
            int intRet = 0;
            sqlDT = objDL.ValidateUser(username, password, out intRet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.Handle(ex);
        OnRaiseErrorOccuredEvent(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex));
    }
    return sqlDT;
}
```

then when i compile having a error like this:

"The out parameter 'return' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method"

Anyone guys can help me solve this.

Comment: What is `sqlDT`? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means in all possibilities (inside and outside the if, in the catch), your result variable must be assigned.

The best approach would be to give it a default value at the start of the function:

```
public DataTable ValidateUser(string username, string password, out int result)
{
    result = 0;
    try
    {
        //Calls the Data Layer (Base Class)
    if (objDL != null)
    {
        int intRet = 0;
        sqlDT = objDL.ValidateUser(username, password, out intRet);
        result = intRet;
    }
//....
```

Comment: thanks it works.. actually I put result = intRet awhile a go but same problem now the work around i made i initialize the value of result to zero first result = 0

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `result` of your method is marked as [**`out`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Parameters marked with `out` must be assigned within your method, i.e

```
result = 5;
```

This is enforced so callers of your method have the guarantee that the parameter that is passed with `out` is always set once your method finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `result` variable in the method.

I'm guessing you want to add an extra line such as

```
result = intRet;
```